# What's the best way to detect if an object is grabbed in SteamVR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I'm currently developing a VR experience where spheres are sound sources and the trackpads control sound volumes through sliders.

What I'm currently trying to achieve, is that when a sphere is grabbed, the trackpad controls the volume, but when the sphere is released the volume stays where it was and the trackpad can no longer interact with the value. That's also because there are multiple spheres in the scene to which I will attach the same scripts.

I am trying to look for tutorials or forums but there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation, does anybody know where to find these kind of controls? I'd like to build a script like:

```
void EnableScripts()
{
if(gameObject == isGrabbed)
    {
     whatever command for enabling the volume change script;
    }
else if(gameObject != isGrabbed)
    {
     whatever command for disabling the volume change script;
    }
}
```

so I guess I would have to use GetComponent to access the script components and be able to enable/disable them, so that's not an issue and I can figure that out.

However, I'm struggling to find a way to tell the script whether a certain sphere is grabbed or not. Any ideas?
(Using SteamVR plugin with the HTC Vive controller).

Comment: https://wirewhiz.com/vr-grabbing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I found the script I'm using to grab the spheres (it's called "Throwable" and it's included in the SteamVR package).

I declared the GameObject slider, used GameObject.Find in the Awake function and made the function public (it was a protected virtual void otherwise). I then looked for the Attach and Detach functions in the script, and added a `slider.SetActive(true);` and `slider.SetActive(false);` respectively. that way the slider would be activated only when grabbing the sphere and deactivated when detached from the hand. I used the GameObject.Find in Awake since when a GameObject is disabled Find. doesn't work (I'm sure there's a more elegant and less resource-heavy way to do it but hey, I'm a beginner)